# Referencing incremental variables in r

Tags: r, variables

I have a number of variables such as `A1 A2 A3 A4` and `B1 B2 B3 B4` and `C1 C2 C3 C4`. I am trying to `cbind` these together into a data frame but the number of variables for `A`, `B` and `C` varies each run. So here the maximum for each is 4, but other times it may be 10 for example.

```
df <- cbind(A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2,B3,B4,C1,C2,C3,C4)

df <- cbind(A1-Amax,B1-Bmax,C1-Cmax)
```

where `max` is a variable containing the max number (i.e 4 in this example).

Comment: I would like to know how those A, B, C objects were created.

Comment: in a loop with goes from i = 1 to max

Comment: Then maybe we should be looking into improving the loop code instead. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Working with apply family and using lists could make more sense.

Comment: Did you meant 'Amax' as the number of 'A' objects or the `max` from the combination of 'A1', "A2', "A3', "A4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `mget` to get a `list` output

```
res <- do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern = "(A|B|C)\\d+")))
```

Suppose if we need it separate to calculate the "Aamax", "Bbmax" etc.

```
lstA <- mget(ls(pattern = "A\\d+"))
lstB <- mget(ls(pattern = "B\\d+"))
lstC <- mget(ls(pattern = "C\\d+"))
```

It is not clear what the "Aamax", "Bbmax" etc.

Comment: "Aamax" - I think they mean `A` with `amax` value, in this case it is `A4`.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. I come from a SAS background and max would be a macro variable to me $max.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in your last question. With respect t your code, what does \\d+ mean?

Comment: @user3651829  Here, we are getting the values of object names that start with 'A' followed by numbers (`\\d+`) from the global environment.